# Supermarket Produce Data Set

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a dataset that describes various types of fruits. The Supermarket Produce Data Set described here seems like a good choice:

http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~siome/papers/rocha-sib08.pdf

However, I tried using the link provided in the paper and it didn't work (http://www.liv.ic.unicamp.br/~undersun/pub/communications.html)

Can someone please tell me where I can find this dataset or another similar?

Comment: HI.. were you able to get a link to download the dataset ? The link in the paper doesn't work, any clues where to download the dataset from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset is available from this page:
http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~rocha/pub/communications.html
Specifically:
http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~rocha/pub/downloads/tropical-fruits-DB-1024x768.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

you can search open food facts for fruit, but after looking at the results, you're going to want to pick through them, as opposed to just returning them.
http://world.openfoodfacts.org/cgi/search.pl?search_terms=Fruit&search_simple=1&action=process

Comment: Sadly, this dataset doesn't help me. I'm searching for images that show only fruits on a controlled background.

Comment: idk what that means, but you should add that requirement to your question